# Keyboard shift key having issues

Tags: keyboard, key, shortcut, paste, shift

Whenever i press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, it causes the same effect as if i pressed the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> shortcut. It pastes the last thing i highlighted over and over. A single press usually causes around 20 or so paste functions. Does anyone know what the issue might be. It is affecting both of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys on my usb external keyboard and the right <kbd>Shift</kbd> key on the laptops keyboard. I have tried updating the driver and it says that it is the most up to date driver. I have made sure the keyboards are clean and they are. I have also made sure that sticky keys is turned off and disabled through the keyboard shortcut. I do not know what setting to change to get rid of this.

If anyone can help, i would greatly appreciate it. Due to it affecting both the standard laptop keyboard as well as the external, i assume it is some setting and not the keyboards themselves. Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: This happened to me using Ditto clipboard manager. The Paste Text hotkey somehow got set to just Shift.

Comment: I had this exact same issue. I was going nuts until I found the solution. I had a laptop and usb keyboard. when I checked https://keyboardtestt.com/ website, it was showing insert key is being pressed. I realized it was due to laptop's inbuilt keyboard malfunction. I tried to disable the laptop keyboard but I couldn't. So I downloaded keyboard re-mapper software from https://atnsoft.com/downloads/ and blocked insert key press event. now the problem went away. The more consistent solution is to disable or remove malfunctioning keyboard from your device.

Answer (score 12):

This happened to me. I had a USB keyboard plugged into my laptop and the main keyboard was doing it. I unplugged it and now it works fine.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem and I figured out that this was due to the "insert" key on the keyboard. This key is located near the "print screen" key. Just check out once. It might have been activated by chance so it pastes whatever is there on the clipboard.Try deactivating it and the problem might get resolved. Good luck...

Answer (score 3):

Press 'esc' key to stop pasting with shift key

Comment: ... that actually worked, weird bug

Answer (score 2):

You just go to any drive *C* or *D* and copy any hidden file.

You can still work with your external keyboard and even if this does not help, check whether your <kbd>insert</kbd> button is pressed down or not.

<kbd>Insert</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> together perform paste function.

Answer (score 1):

Just unplug the usb keyboard and again plug in.. 
It will work fine
Good Luck

Comment: It worked for me.